# Unable to Insert \ Update using EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, console-application

I am creating an ASP.Net MVC application and I have created a new console application just so that I can pass it a few parameters and use the DataContext in the MVC application so that I dont have to continually repeat myself.

This is the code that I am using

```
using mySite.WebSite.DataModel;

namespace mySite.AvailabilityManager
{
class Program 
{
    public static List<DateTime>Availability = new List<DateTime>(); 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var startingDt = Convert.ToDateTime("04-09-2015 08:00:00");
        var endingDt = Convert.ToDateTime("04-09-2015 17:00:00");
        CreateAvailabilty(startingDt, endingDt);
        AddAvailabilityToDatabase();
    }

    public static void CreateAvailabilty(DateTime startingDt, DateTime endingDt)
    {
        var hoursDiff = endingDt.Subtract(startingDt);
        for (int i = 0; i < hoursDiff.Hours; i++)
        {
            Availability.Add(startingDt);
            startingDt = startingDt.AddHours(1);
        }
    }

    public static void AddAvailabilityToDatabase()
    {

        using (var db = new FitnessForAllContext())
        {
            foreach (var availableDate in Availability.Select(date => new AvailableDate {DateAvailable = date}))
            {
                db.AvailableDates.Add(availableDate);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

When I get to `db.AvailableDates.Add(..)` I get this error

> No connection string named 'MyDBContext' could be found in the application config file.

I was under the impression that because I am using the reference from my MVC application and the connection string is in the ASP.Net MVC config file that I would not have to repeat the connection string in my app.config file for the console application.

So, to summaries,

1. I have the MVC Project refernece in my console application
2. This fails because of the lack of a connection string at `db.AvailableDates.Add(availableDate);`
3. The mySite.Website assembly is being pulled through into my bin debug folder

If you could offer some insight as to what I need to do without having to continually repeat myself by adding the connection string everywhere I intend on using this, unless I REALLY have to repeat myself

Comment: add a `MyDBContext` in your local config.

Comment: Copy your connection string from App.Config to Web.Config (or Startup project)

Comment: i thought it might be the case... had copied it but wanted to know if there was an alternative method i could have used.

Comment: The .NET configuration system generally uses a single configuration file and the default name is `ApplicationName.exe.config` which is created from the `App.config` in your C# project. So your console application is only configured from the `App.config` of that project and not from any other configuration files in other projects. ASP.NET uses a more complicated model where the configuration files are a hierarchy of `web.config` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a constant or an embedded resource or anything IN your EntityFramework project that contains connection string. But I think, it's not a good practice, every executing project should have it's own configuration.

Comment: i thought that may be the case

Answer (score 2):

Standard, the connection string needs to be in de config file of the startup project. In this case of the console application. The config of the referenced project is ignored.